# .Net Core Web API with ServiceFabric MinRequestBodyDataRate

Tags: c#, rest, .net-core, service-fabric-stateless

So we have a .Net Core 3.1 Web Api hosted on Service Fabric.
For some requests we use Http Get with a body (yes I know it's not pretty but it's not forbidden) because we want to retrieve some data and so Http Get is the verb to use accoding to REST api.

We made some test and on a "normal" web api without Service Framework it works fine to put a body on a Get Request, but then when we use this on our Api with service fabric we have a
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException: Reading the request body timed out due to data arriving too slowly. See MinRequestBodyDataRate.`

I already try : `opt.Limits.MinRequestBodyDataRate = null;` in the UseKestrel

When we change the method from Get to Post it's works.

So I was wondering if there was something specials with Service Fabric (maybe with the reverse Proxy) that made our request fail?

Have anyone some clue on what is happening?

Thanks